# Trying to access the environment object created inside scene delegate by another scenedelegate function

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode12, environmentobject

I have created an environment object in my scendelegate and want to also use it in another function that resides inside my scenedelegate. The code looks as follows:

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
    class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
        //@EnvironmentObject var data: DataFetcher
        var data = DataFetcher()
    
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
 
            if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
                
                let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                let data = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).self.data
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(data))
                self.window = window
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
        
        func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink){
            guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
                print("That's weird. My dynamic link object has no url")
                return
            }
            print("Your incoming link parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")
            guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false),
                let queryItems = components.queryItems else {return}
            self.data.linkRecieved = true
            print(data.linkRecieved)
        }
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
            _ = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
                guard error == nil else{
                    print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                    self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the environment object's linkRecieved variable is not changed inside contentview when the handleIncomingDynamicLink function is executed (I have verified the variable is indeed changed to true once the function is run). Any insight in fixing this issue is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Is `DataFetcher` an `ObservableObject`? Is `linkReceived` a `@Published` property?

Comment: @NewDev yes to both

Comment: I don't understand this line `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).self.data` - Why is it not simply `self.data`?

Comment: @NewDev to allow the environment object to be accessed in the appdelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned a `DataFetcher` instance to the `data` property, presumably to set its type and eliminate the error that your property isn't initialised.

Then in `willConnectTo` you get the `DataFetcher` instance from your `AppDelegate.  Your` data`property and the local`data`variable in`willConnectTo`(That you subsequently add to the environment) now reference different instances of`DataFetcher`, but you didn't realise.

I am not a big fan of assigning "throw away" instances to properties for this reason.

A better approach is to use an implicitly unwrapped optional.  That way if you don't assign a value to the property you will get a crash and quickly work out that something isn't right.

Then in `willConectTo` you can assign the instance from your `AppDelegate` to the property and put it in the environment.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
        //@EnvironmentObject var data: DataFetcher
        var data: DataFetcher!
    
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
 
            if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
                
                let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                self.data = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).self.data
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(data))
                self.window = window
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject that `var data` which is property, so remove the following line

```
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
//let data = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).self.data // << this one
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: 
   ContentView().environmentObject(self.data))   // << inject own property
```

Comment: If I remove that line won't I loose access to the environment object in the app delegate?

Comment: What do you mean? Would you add AppDelegate code to your question?